# Orbeon Form Builder Repository

Tags: xpath, orbeon, xforms

How can multiple users work on same project / same form at a time?

Something like a repository.

In our project there are multiple sections & work is divided on these sections. We tried to save the same form from different systems but form saves only recent data (recently saved form).

Is there a method to club or merge code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching I found an alternative.

We are team of 4 & we spitted our work based on the Sections. Make sure that each developer should have Unique Section.

Go through the Orbeon Source & Collapse XML Tags shown in Image.

[image]

after doing this your code should look like above.

Point #1: Copy your other sections here

Point #2: Copy your Binding Code.

Point #3: Copy your Services & Actions

Point #4: Copy your form sections.

This is how we merged 4 different application. 
Few things to be checked

1. Repeated Grid
2. Actions
3. Services

All the best! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

At this point, Orbeon Forms and Form Runner don't support multiple users editing exactly the same form data. Of course, multiple users can at the same time edit multiple "instances" (form data) of the same "form" (form definition).

So, I would, if possible in your case, restructure the form, maybe splitting it into multiple forms, to avoid that situation.

Comment: Oh okay, it would be better if you can release in next version. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: We have an [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1067) about detecting a conflict situation.

Answer (score 0):

Using Git, each user can work on their own copy of a form, regularly committing changes and pushing to the main branch.  Occasionally there will be merge conflicts, but if each user only updates a specific section then conflicts should be get to a minimum and not too complex.

Orbeon persistence can also be configured so that form code can be saved directly to text files.